# Adding up all primes between 50 and 70 - Why is my code not working?

Tags: python, primes

Code:

```
counter = 50
total = 0
for i in range(counter, 70):
    is_prime = True
    for j in range(2, i):
        remainder = i % j
        print("i is : ", i, "   - and j is : ", j, " and the remainder is : ", remainder)
        if remainder == 0:
            is_prime = False
            print("remainder = ", remainder,", so ", i, "is not a prime")
    if is_prime:
        total += i
    else:
        print(i, " is a prime")
print(total)
```

So if you run the code, it will first say "50 is not a prime", but then later it says "50 is a prime".
And I don't get that. I'm setting the **is_prime** BOOLEAN to True only before I run the test loop. During the test loop, if the number is NOT a prime, it will set **is_prime** to False. So in my mind, the **is_prime** is not set back to True (not until the next iteration of the loop starts), so the number(I) should be identified as 'not a prime'.
Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Break the inner loop when remainder==0

Comment: I tried that, but that doesn't work...

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/oVRXVs0.png

Answer (score 3):

It's the logic... if is prime is False it is not prime. You got that part backwards.

```
if is_prime:
    print(i, " is a prime")
    total += i
else:
    print(i, " is not a prime")
```

Comment: Owww dangit.. so my calculations were right. My last print statement was wrong..
So stupid.. 
Thanks for pointing that out..   :-)